# Jquery plugin writing: How do I use the options in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So I'm converting a plugin. Originally I had a traditional javascript function with some variables I pass in, but I wanted to make it a full Jquery plugin with options. The documentation shows you how to set them up, but not how to use them in your code. Here's a bit of the code:

```
jQuery.fn.placeholderRX = function(options) {
    var settings = jQuery.extend({
        hoverColor: '#fff',
        addClass: 'null',
        textColor: '#FBFBFB'        
    }, options);

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.children('.inputSpan').each(function() {      
            $(this).children('.inputText').hover( 
                function() {
                    $input.children('.input').css('background-color', hoverColor);
                },
                function() {
                    $input.children('.input').css('background-color', revertColor);
                }
            );
        }       
    });
};
```

How would I pass that color option value to the hover function beneath it? Or more simply, can I just pass the option value to a variable?

Comment: Try... $input.children('.input').css('background-color', settings['hoverColor'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared a variable called `settings`. You can access the `hoverColor` property of that object with `settings.hoverColor`:

```
$input.children('.input').css('background-color', settings.hoverColor);
```

The `options` argument to your plugin will be an object too. When you pass that in, the `extend` method will merge the contents of the `options` object and the "defaults" object, and you assign the result of that merge to `settings`.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
$input.children('.input').css('background-color', settings.hoverColor);
```

Or what jcreamer898 said works as well:

```
$input.children('.input').css('background-color', settings['hoverColor']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
$input.children('.input').css('background-color', settings['hoverColor'])
```